# Was the actress Winona Ryder laughing in the dinner scene or was it in the script?

Tags: beetlejuice

In the banana song scene in [*Beetlejuice* (1988)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094721/), when Lydia (Winona Ryder) gets up from the table she starts laughing. She can even be heard [right in the middle of the scene](https://youtu.be/nN5lIEcbXpM?t=63), and a little later is seen [convulsed with laughter](https://youtu.be/nN5lIEcbXpM?t=74).

Was Lydia's reaction in the script or was it Winona Ryder's real reaction to the scene and intentionally left in the final cut?

Comment: The reaction fits with the scene but it is odd they didn't give her a close-up if it was intentional.

Comment: *"In the script"* Yes, it's in the [shooting script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/beetlejuice_skaaren_final.html), kind of: *"A look of **sheer delight comes across Lydia's face**, unlike anything we have previously seen.  She dances and claps her hands in time with the music. **She is in teen heaven**."*

Comment: @Walt is it not worth answering?

Comment: What does "laughing over" mean?

Comment: @Walt ... I think that's the point, given the editing doesn't exactly highlight her reaction, was her reaction simply the actress laughing at her colleagues, or was it scripted.  I think you have an answer.

Comment: OK, I put it up. Sorry for the delay. I guess she *is* kind of doubling over in that second clip. But I still can't hear her laughing in the first one, even with the volume way up. Can someone pinpoint the exact second?

Comment: @Walt The second clip is actually the same with the first clip. I've just inserted the correct times into the url. You can hear Winona's laughter and watch her doubling over further in the clip for a second time if you watch it carefully. I can't get myself from laughing and giggling whenever I watch this scene so I don't blame the actors themselves doing the same. I even think that Jeffrey Jones' first reaction to Catherine O'Hara's singing is a non-scripted behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lydia was indeed supposed to be delighted by their possession. Here's the bit in [the shooting script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/beetlejuice_skaaren_final.html) that details her character's reaction right when they all start dancing:

> A look of **sheer delight comes across Lydia's face**, unlike anything we have previously seen.  She dances and claps her hands in time with the music. **She is in teen heaven.**
> [...]
>
> Lydia **excitedly** looks around the room to see if she can see the ghosts. She can't.

So whether Ryder was acting or rather was genuinely amused and used that energy for her character, her jubilant reaction *was* originally in the script.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer but I guess we can't know the real situation except the participants of that scene take. So if in future someone contributes with a testimony from the crew the acceptance can go to their answer. Thanks.